# Most efficient approach in inherited fields?

Tags: java

Consider a certain class hierarchy consisting of a root class and some subclasses

```
    R
    |
 .--+--+------.
 |     |  ... |
S1     S2 ... Sn
```

Class R has a field `x` of a certain type, say `X`, which is not a simple type, that every subclass should inherit. Subclasses can do sorts of internal processing on field `x` as well as expose it as a property.
Sort of a discussion arose about which of these two coding style was preferrable:

#### 1st solution

Have class `R` declare `x` as a private field and provide public getter and setter

```
class R {
    ....
    private X x;

    ....

    public X getX() { ... }
    public void setX(X ax) { ... }
}
```

#### 2nd solution

Have class `R` declare `x` as a protected field

Which one, in your opinion, could be the preferrable solution?

Comment: Why are you using straight subclassing anyway? This should generally be avoided because it creates a tight coupling between classes which you can usually avoid. rule of thumb: prefer collaboration to extension (and prefer interfaces to superclasses)

Comment: That hierarchy represents a hierarchy of backbeans, in which I have moved all the common/boilerplate code in the base class (R). Every subclass is a backbean pertaining to various jsf pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to allow to be done to the inner X. If you want it to be accessible/modifiable from outside make public get/set. But if you want them to be only modifiable by its subclasses then use protected and that is all. IMHO

Comment: You could also make protected getters/setters instead of letting subclasses access a protected field directly. A bit more encapsulation.

Comment: @Adriaan Koster very good comment. If variables are meant to be 'fully' accessible for subclasses then you should have direct access to them, they should be protected no need for methods. But then if you are making an API or you are not completely certain of the class design, thus in order to protect your code from future changes, doing as you are saying would be the best option. There is lots of issues involved here, for example, 'faster' direct access versus code modifiability. In the end it all depends on what is the use of the parent class, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

if you want your subclasses to be access the variable, protected. It you want your subclasses to use methods to modify it then make it private.

All depens on the access u want other classes to have on it.

Edit: (First Solution)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use inheritance this is safest way:

```
class R
{
  private X x;

  protected X getX()
  {
    return this.x;
  }
}
```

Why not having `R` as a separate class and reference it from `S1, S2, ... Sn`?

Answer (score 0):

The private field is preferable. However, you should not change the internal state of another object anyway from another class even if it is a subclass.

Sound as if you insert huge coupling between R, S1, S2, etc, and X. Better consider alternative object oriented design, distributing the responsibilities clearly among the objects.

Consider having a look at the Liskov substitution principle before subclassing.